# how to fix :unsatisfiableerror: the following specifications were found to be in conflict

Tags: python, python-3.x

As shown in lecture "python for computer vision with opencv and deep learning"(udemy course)I was creating a environment with yml file provided with the course. I get the following error

```
unsatisfiableerror: the following specifications were found to be in conflict: - mkl==2019.0=118 - mkl_random==1.0.1=py36h77b88f5_1 -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0']use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

here are the 2 packages that's troubling me

```
mkl 2019.0 118
--------------
file name   : mkl-2019.0-118.tar.bz2
name        : mkl
version     : 2019.0
build string: 118
build number: 118
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
size        : 178.1 MB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : proprietary - Intel
license_family: Proprietary
md5         : 90ec1f3a6ebafff38eec2d318ef8cf52
platform    : None
subdir      : win-64
timestamp   : 1537292603098
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/mkl-2019.0-118.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    intel-openmp

mkl_random 1.0.1 py36h77b88f5_1
-------------------------------
file name   : mkl_random-1.0.1-py36h77b88f5_1.tar.bz2
name        : mkl_random
version     : 1.0.1
build string: py36h77b88f5_1
build number: 1
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
size        : 268 KB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : BSD 3-Clause
md5         : a620e0e1acb966de2071824225183022
platform    : None
subdir      : win-64
timestamp   : 1531594541407
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/mkl_random-1.0.1-py36h77b88f5_1.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    blas 1.0 mkl
    numpy >=1.11.3,<2.0a0
    python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0
    vc 14.*
    mkl >=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0
```

Comment: as you can see, `mkl_random` requires a version of `mkl` >= 2018.0.3 < 2.019.0a0, but you have `mkl 2019.0 118` as a dependency. That's irreconcilable. You'll need to downgrade `mkl` (or upgrade `mkl_random` if appropriate)

Comment: @AdamSmith how do you downgrade mkl package? is it possible to change mkl version in yml file using text editor.

Comment: Since you're following the Udemy course and it seems like it's being maintained, why don't you ask the instructor rather than StackOverflow? I ask because I don't know what features the course is going to be using that might require certain versions of each package.

Comment: @AdamSmith I got this course from friend, so I didnt actually subscribe to udemy course. So I am looking for solution in StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

open the yml file in a text editor like notepad, then simply delete that line with the error . the yml field is just a text file

Comment: thanks for the answer, I edited the 2019 version with 2018, it worked